# Lie Algebra of a connected simple linear algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group and $A=K[G]$  (K is a field of characterstic 0)  be the coordinate ring of $G$. In Humphreys, the Lie algebra of $G$ is defined as the space of left invariant derivations of $A$ , i.e, $\mathfrak{L}(G) = \{\delta \in Der \hspace{1mm} A $ | $\delta \lambda_x = \lambda_x \delta $ for all $x \in G$  }

Note that $\lambda_x : K[G] \to K[G]$ sending $\hspace{1mm} f(y) \mapsto f(x^{-1}y) $.

1. Now, if we are given a connected simple algebraic group over $C$ (i.e , the defining polynomial equations of the underlying variety are over $C$), how do we see that its Lie algebra is simple ?
2. Further, given a simple Lie algebra how do we see that there exists a simply connected algebraic group $G$ with Lie algebra isomorphic to this given simple Lie algebra?

Please give reference to specific material which I can read to understand  these claims. Any hints to the above claims would be highly appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Note that part 2 uses in an essential way what the base field is, as there are simple Lie algebras in positive characteristic which do not come from any algebraic groups.

Comment: Part 1 is also false in characteristic $p$, e.g., for $G=\mathrm{PGL}_p$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft   Is the simply connected algebraic group $G$ claimed to exist as in point 2 of the question defined over $C$ ?

Comment: @YCor  Is the simply connected algebraic group $G$ claimed to exist as in point 2 of the question defined over $C$ ?

Comment: In fact any simple, connected, simply connected algebraic group is defined over $\mathbb{Z}$. I am not sure how easy this is to prove, though as far as I recall, it is basically by construction.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Note: $C$ is just a field and not the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ . I would really appreciate if you could elaborate your comment as I am just a beginner in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Well, once it is defined over $\mathbb{Z}$, it is defined over any ring, in particular over any field.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Does this result hold for all simply connected algebraic groups or do we need to include 'simple' in the hypothesis? I mean in ur comment do u mean the group needs to be simple as well as simply connected ? or is it valid for simple as well as simply connected algebraic groups ? Thanks for helping !

Comment: As far as I recall, this holds in general for reductive groups, and the part about being simply connected is not important for this particular claim (i.e. being defined over $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: I am curious about part 1. Does it holds in positive characteristic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the possible references are Milne's [lectures notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LAG.pdf). In Proposition $4.1$ it is proved that a connected algebraic group $G$ is semisimple if and only if its Lie algebra is semisimple. Then 1. follows together with Theorem $4.5$. Theorem $4.22$ shows the claim 2, for fields of characteristic zero.